# TypeScript - Multiple source files, single file output and Inheritance

Tags: inheritance, typescript

I am just looking for some advice and clarification on something that has bothered me twice in the past in my TypeScript projects.

Consider when you have 2 files such as this

```
//Animal.ts
class Animal{
   move(): void;
} 

//Dog.ts
class Dog extends Animal{

}
```

If your output is a single .js file, you get an error similar to "Dog cannot extend Undefined" when you run the JavaScript file.

It seemed to me that Dog was being interpreted before Animal had been and so Dog could not extend Animal.

What is going on here and how do you prevent this? I sometimes find myself thinking... I could extend X but I am hesitant due to my previous issues.

Thanks!

Comment: That shouldn't happen, I've just tried your code in VS2013 (Update2) with TS 1.0 and it produces the correct output i.e. Animal first then extends function and then Dog. Which version of TS are you using?

Comment: Hey Ross, thanks for trying that! I am in the same environment but that may have been a poor example. Perhaps because Animal is alphabetically before Dog in the generated --out file.  Maybe if Animal extended Dog (lame test) the test would fail.

Comment: Yeah good point, just tried swapping them around it and fails, as you said.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up in concrete for me anyway. This explains why some previous projects worked for me, and some did not and it was not knowing why which caused me to be nervous about the subject. Your test is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `--out` the order you pass these files to `tsc` is *important*. That determines the generated JavaScript.

The TypeScript team recommends you use a `reference.ts` file to ensure the order : https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts#javascript-generation-and-ordering